# Importar arquivo de texto para listbox (drive)

Tags: vb.net

Olá, eu tenho tentado importar um arquivo de texto para uma listbox, lendo-o linha por linha, porém, com a diferença de que esse arquivo de texto não está em lugar algum do pc, mas sim no meu google drive. Estou utilizando esse código:

```
Dim R As IO.StreamReader
Dim Opt As String = web.DownloadString("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=(ID_AQUI)&export=download")

 R = New IO.StreamReader(Opt)
    While (R.Peek() > -1)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(R.ReadLine)
    End While
    R.Close()
```

Porém, quando ele tenta importar, retorna o seguinte erro:

> - $exception  {"Caracteres inválidos no caminho."}    System.ArgumentException

E eu já tentei usar System Encoding, e não resolveu meu problema, eu consigo fazer funcionar se eu escrever primeiro em um arquivo de texto o conteúdo do arquivo do google drive, e depois importar o arquivo de texto criado, porém, isso é muito lento, e eu gostaria de agilidade. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Já experimentou alterar o _Encoding_ do _WebClient_? **wb.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8**.